# Does uniform continuity of bounded continuous functions implies the same for all continuous functions on a uniform space?

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, uniform-spaces

Recently I came to know about Atsuji space from [the paper](https://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v30/tp30120.pdf)<sup>1</sup>. A metric space $X$ is called an Atsuji space if every real-valued continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous. Strikingly I have found in the above paper that, **$X$ is an Atsuji space if and only if every bounded real-valued continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous.**

I would like to ask whether the same can be concluded for a uniform space.

**That is, can we conclude the following:**

> **For an uniform space $(X,\mathcal U),$ every real-valued continuous function (w.r.t. the topology induced by $\mathcal U$) on $X$ is uniformly continuous if and only if every bounded real-valued continuous function on $X$ is uniformly continuous.**

*Unfortunately I failed to construct a counterexample and consequently some help.*

---

<sup>1</sup> *Kundu, S.; Jain, Tanvi*, Atsuji spaces: equivalent conditions, Topol. Proc. 30, No. 1, 301-325 (2006). [ZBL1123.54004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1123.54004), [MR2280674](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2280674).

Comment: You should maybe ask for completeness of your uniform space. Metric Atsuji spaces are indeed complete, this comes from one of the equivalent definitions:  every pseudo-Cauchy sequence with distinct terms in (X, d) has a cluster point (this might still be true for any uniform space).

Answer (score 1):

To construct a counterexample, start with any completely regular topological space $T$ for which there are unbounded continuous functions (that is, the space is not pseudocompact). For example, $T$ can be the real line with the usual topology or an infinite set with the discrete topology. Let $S$ be the uniform space projectively generated by all bounded continuous functions on $T$; in other words, the coarsest uniform space on the set $T$ for which all bounded continuous functions are uniformly continuous. Then $S$ and $T$ have the same topology, hence the same continuous functions. But $S$ is precompact because it is projectively generated by mappings to precompact spaces (bounded intervals on the real line). Therefore every uniformly continuous function on $S$ is bounded.

Comment: why is $S$ precompact?

Comment: @erz $S$ is precompact because it is projectively generated by mappings to precompact spaces. I have updated the answer.